# Compressing Torrents

Tags: torrents

So I am trying to download a torrent to my tablet, but it is 51.67 gb, which is HUMONGOUS. Any way to compress it and make it fit into my tablet?

Comment: Flagging as off topic since it seems to be asking for software recommendations. Although, it's asking about torrents as well, and I'm not sure if this goes against community guidelines or not.

Comment: Download it from computer, compress it & put it in your device..

Comment: On most torrent clients, you can select which files do you want to download. You can download some first, then do something to them to reduce the filesize (though audio/video file won't get better size because it's *already* compressed) or save it to external storage, then download the rest. Rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot compress files from torrents before they finish downloading. The [torrent file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torrent_file) contains a list of the blocks and their correct hashes. Your torrent client needs to download these blocks to the filesystem and check their hashes.

You are free to reencode or compress content once the torrent is downloaded, but this will not help you on a storage-constrained tablet.

Comment: Could I download it on my computer, compress it, then transfer it to my tablet?

Comment: @Kindler Yes, but it's simpler to move only some files in the torrent.

Answer (score 0):

You could try raring or zipping the files into parts. But saving space is minimal. I guess you don't have an otg?

Comment: How are you going to rar the torrent before it has downloaded?